# How to enable IP access filter on Spark Worker?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a java application that starts up a spark worker:

`Worker.startRpcEnvAndEndpoint(args.host(), args.port(), args.webUiPort(), args.cores(), args.memory(), args.masters(), args.workDir(), scala.Option.empty(), conf);`

(see https://books.japila.pl/spark-standalone-internals/Worker/#externalshuffleservice)

I would now like to set up an IP access filter so that I have a hard coded list of IP addresses that can access this service.

Is there a way to configure the Java program above to provide such an IP access filter?

Comment: I feel like using certificates would be a better than restricting to IPs, at least in cloud environments where IPs frequently change, otherwise, use your OS firewall rules

Comment: i agree with all these things. this is in a hypothetical system where admins demand zero-trust ip filters on all java service ports *in addition* to the other security controls.

Comment: From code, I don't think there's much you can do here via the Spark API. You can try modifying the RPC bind address subnets for the workers, but that's about it

Comment: that was my conclusion too. will require code changes on spark side. you can convert that to answer if u want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of Spark internal networking, but from a server bind-address perspective, the best you can do is to isolate the bind address on a specific interface/subnet - this would start with your `args.host()`

If you want to restrict to specific IPs within that subnet, you'll need to work with the OS firewall, maybe managing that from code as well, but not with the Spark libraries.

Then going further - restricting to certain *clients*, rather than machines, you could provide certificates into certain machines, or users, or otherwise encode IP addresses into some auth protocol, then enforce ACL policies for Spark. Perhaps you can use Kerberos for this, too